# HTML <br /> tag breaks display: block

Tags: word-wrap, css

I have this jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/sqszH/1/

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to get the Hello World text to come underneath of the "long long long long" text directly under it.  Is there a way to do this without changing the HTML?

Cause I have a similar situation on a webpage, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  It's probably something really simple too.  Perhaps someone can give me a hand here?  That would be awesome!

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
<div class="first-span">first span</div>
    <div class="second-span">some long long long long long long long long long long text<br /><span>Hello World</span></div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    width:100%;
}
.first-span{
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.second-span{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.clear
{
 clear: both;   
}
```

Comment: Ok, I actually changed this to `box-sizing: border-box` instead of `display: block`, but they both act the same.  And I know these are not spans, they are divs.

Comment: i don't get what you want ? How exactly do you want to position the Hello world text ?

Comment: How can I get it underneath of the very long text that is to the right of the "first span" text?  Cause right now, I'm seeing "Hello World" directly underneath of "first span" text instead.

Comment: Resize the Result column down in width and you will see what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `display` property of the `second-span` class to `table`

```
.second-span{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display: table;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ryFx)

Answer (score 0):

Add   `height: 4em;`

```
.first-span{
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 1em;
    height: 4em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sqszH/4/

Comment: Thanks, but what if you don't know the height?  For example, if it's different on different browsers?

Comment: I didn't know the height, I just made it big enough to work.  I like @axrwkr's solution better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

edited solution because i misunderstood the question:

if you know the width of your second-span div, float it left too. then you'll have the "hellow world" text right under the loooong text.

if not, you have just the option to set the hight on the fist-span as already mentioned or change the html.

Comment: No, I don't want it under there.  I want it under the rest of the text that the `div` is within.  Steve Wellens understands, but what if I don't know the height?

Comment: do you know the width of the second-span div? if so, float it left too and you got what you want.